# Why is my question 'How would the main clause be corrected' on-hold?

Tags: support, close-reasons

My question was kept on hold due to off-topic as it was a proofreading question. Being my first question, I did not know as to what kind of questions to be posted. After going through the rule of off-topic, I have edited my post to a specific topic but still the question is kept on hold.

Comment: Well, [it got two reopen votes in review before being removed from the queue by three leave closed choices](http://ell.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/32013). If someone edits it further, or someone who hasn't yet voted adds their reopen vote, it would get another chance at getting the other three votes needed before three leave opens land on it again.

Comment: Thank you @Nathan Tuggy for letting me know. Can I edit the question further or someone has to edit?

Comment: Anybody can edit it, although you're almost certainly the best candidate to do so, since at this point it's mostly as polished as anyone else could make it. It would probably be helpful to add some more about what you think might be a good correction, or a correction you *don't* think would work. More examples might help too.